# Public environment variables from Next.js not working in Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-functions, environment-variables, azure-static-web-app

I had my app previously deployed on Vercel, but since I'm using Azure AD and MongoDB on Azure, I'm moving the hosting of my app to Azure as well for decreased networking delays.

I set all my environment variables under Configuration -> Application Settings in the Production environment. The private variables (e.g. client secrets) are perfectly readable by my Next.js back-end, but my front-end cannot read the environment variables prefixed by NEXT_PUBLIC, even though this previously worked in my other projects on Vercel and Google Cloud Platform.

Printing the public environment variables (NEXT_PUBLIC_*) to the console returns `undefined`.

**How do I make a distinction between full-stack and server-side environment variables? Because NEXT_PUBLIC does not seem to work.**

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Under the `build_and_deploy_job` -> `steps`, add a field named `env`. Under this, you can place your environment variables like this:

```
env:
  NEXT_PUBLIC_VARIABLE: "value1"
  NEXT_PUBLIC_ANOTHER_VARIABLE: "value2"
```

You can find my full .yml file [here](https://gist.github.com/wouter-deen/056711238cca261e7b52482fa22276c2).

I want to express the fact that this is a suboptimal solution and for the multi-billion dollar company that Microsoft is, you should be able to place public/client-side environment variables directly in your Static Web App via the Azure web portal.