How to Properly Use Environment Variables on the Client Side in Azure Static Web Apps with Next.js?
I'm facing an issue with my Next.js app after migrating from Vercel to Azure. Previously, I was using environment variables on the client side in a straightforward manner by adding them in Vercel settings and accessing them in the app like with a casual way without any twist. Like this: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_URL anywhere in the app.
This setup worked perfectly on Vercel. However, after moving the frontend to Azure, I can't make the environment variables visible on the client side.
(Or I can, but it cannot be really the most efficient way to do so)
I've read many sources and tried different solutions, but nothing seems to work consistently. The only way I found that works involves the following steps:

Adding environment variables to Azure Environment settings.
Adding them to GitHub Actions secrets.
Including them in the yml file.

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.*** }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/frontend" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
        env:
          NEXT_PUBLIC_URL: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL }}
          NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: ${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL }}
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######


Defining them in next.config.js.

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        NEXT_PUBLIC_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL,
        NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig

Additionally, I have to include an empty getServerSideProps function that returns an empty prop to make it work in each route file in the pages folder. This seems overly complicated and not an ideal solution.
import getConfig from 'next/config'

// This may look weird, but it's necessary because of Azure cannot pick env vars if this is not here. Yes, really.
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    return {
        props: {},
    }
}

const Page = () => {
    const {publicRuntimeConfig} = getConfig()
    const {NEXT_PUBLIC_URL, NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL} = publicRuntimeConfig
    console.log(NEXT_PUBLIC_URL)
    console.log(NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL)

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}</p>
            <p>{NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Page

Is there a better way to handle environment variables for the client side in Azure Static Web Apps with Next.js?
Tech stack:

Next.js 14.2.3 (pages folder)
React
Apollo GraphQL
Azure Static Web App
GitHub Actions
other not relevant things

Thank you for your help in advance
Br
Tottzi

Have you tried it by adding secrets in GitHub?

@Harshitha Yes, It's there up in the list, what I did to make i work. I can get the variables but not in a client component. Only if I run getserverside props empty in the route file.

I like this comment that is related.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75025009/12519806

Check it once from your side.

@Harshitha, I've been struggling with this issue and would greatly appreciate any guidance. Is there a better way to handle environment variables on the client side in Azure Static Web Apps with Next.js? If I remove getServerSideProps, it stops working. Normally, I don't ask for help here and can usually find solutions on my own, but this time my attempts haven't been efficient at all. It's not like I turn on/off the pc and it works.

What does client side in azure static web app mean?

If possible can you share your code repo?

@Harshitha No, I can't do. client side means that U can see in the snippet I pasted in.
const Page = () => {...} There I cannot reach the process.env....
I can get it in the pages/api/something.tsx file, I can also get it in a route in the getServerSideProps. That part works, but not in any other places in my app. F.e. I make a component that should do different things according to the chosen environment, I cannot do so. process.env.something does not available in any component only on serverside. It works on vercel, but my company wants to move to Azure.

So, there's no way to make it work with Azure. The variables need to be set in GitHub instead, and within the YAML files, the variables should be referenced as vars.... It's not possible to expose the environment variables from Azure on the client side using the "pages" folder in Next.js.
